# Restrictions on variables of two functions in order to be larger and smaller relative to each other

Tags: inequalities

I have two functions

```
  f1[x_, y_] := -1 + x - Sqrt[8 + x^2 + (1 - x) (1 + x)];
  f2[x_, y_] := -1 - x - Sqrt[8 y^2 + (1 - 3 x) (1 - x) + x^2];
```

I am searching the restriction and the relation between `x` and `y` in which `f1 > f2`. Also other condition in which `f1<f2`. But unfortunately I don't know what function must be used.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot[f1[x, y] == f2[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` and `Plot3D[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: Satisfying "`f1 > f2` and `f1 < f2`" is impossible.

Comment: @m_goldberg I guess OP means larger or smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By trial and error, if we plot

```
    Plot3D[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we see that

```
 x== 1-y^2
```

is the boundary?

```
   ContourPlot[{f1[x, y] == f2[x, y], x == 1 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> {, Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Indeed

```
 eq = f1[x, y]^2 == f2[x, y]^2 // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 eq /. x -> 1 - y^2 // FullSimplify // PowerExpand
```

(* True *)

Answer (score 7):

```
re = Reduce[f1[x, y] < f2[x, y], {x, y}, Reals]
Reduce[f1[x, y] > f2[x, y], {x, y}, Reals]
```

> `x < 1 && -Sqrt[1 - x] < y < Sqrt[1 - x]`
>
> `(x <= 1 && (y < -Sqrt[1 - x] || y > Sqrt[1 - x])) || x > 1`

**Edit:** You can also directly plot the reduced result.

```
RegionPlot[re, {x, -10, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
f1[x_, y_] := -1 + x - Sqrt[8 + x^2 + (1 - x) (1 + x)];
f2[x_, y_] := -1 - x - Sqrt[8 y^2 + (1 - 3 x) (1 - x) + x^2];
```

we have a solution for `f1[x, y] > f2[x, y]`

```
CylindricalDecomposition[f1[x, y] > f2[x, y], {y, x}]
(* x > 1 - y^2 *)
```

`CylindricalDecomposition` is well worth investigating if you need to analyse inequalities.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this function.